# Best way of creating 2D mesh from curve?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

just wanted to know if there is a quicker way of creating a 2D mesh from a bezier curve?

Right now i just end up with some kind triangular shape that i have to delete the bottom vertices from, and then set the Z axis on the remaining vertices to 0.

Using the 2D option instead of the 3D doesn't have any effect for my purpose.

Here is a demo of my current method:
https://youtu.be/YL23LZxlYHA

Answer (score 3):

You can switch ***Fill***  option to ***Front*** so you don't have the lower part
 :
[image]

or you create another Curve and flat it on the Y axis and use it as a bevel  object :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a new plane object and scale to the width of desired mesh.

Add an array modifier then a curve modifier to the plane.

Increase count in array modifier until mesh is length of curve.